# dpkg-query --show [package-name] prints out uninstalled packages

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I removed mysql from Ubuntu server completely as below

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deluser mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5
```

When I run `dpkg-query -l` there is no mysql package listed. However, when I do `dpkg-query --show mysql-server` it prints out `mysql-server`

It must return "There is no package mysql-server installed" but I'm not sure why it shows mysql-server is installed.

Comment: It should? It does query information about packages from the database, and even though you purged the package from your system, `dpkg` likely sees no reason to erase the database records as well. I suspect this works as designed.

Comment: So how can I erase database records?

Comment: Try pruning them from `/var/lib/dpkg/available`.